# arquivo htaccess dando forbidden

Tags: php, apache

Estou usando o Uniform S
erver, que é um servidor portátil, e já está com o mod_rewrite ativo e mesmo assim o meu arquivo htaccess retorna forbidden.

arquivo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

O que está errado?

Comment: Se remover o .htaccess o erro continua?

Answer (score 1):

Completamente diferente tente:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: ainda forbidden

Comment: editei vê aí acho que vai.

Comment: eu mudei de servidor e funcionou com o meu original, mas no servidor portátil n...

Comment: Tenta com esse código que postei...